# nginx 301 redirect after changing structure of url

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

I have this blog (wordpress...) and i changed its permalinks in the follwoing way:

OLD : `http://www.example.com/2015/05/04/my-post`
NEW: `http://www.example.com/my-post`

so i simply removed the date from the link. the problem is i have many posts (thousands) published all over the net with the old structure.
there are qordpress plugins that allows you to create 301 redirect for a specific request but is there a way in the server level where i can do this 301 redirect without dealing with plugins etc..
the structure is consistent so even though i never worked with regex i guess it can help me here?? any other solutions will be highly appreciated ..thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this rewrite statement somewhere in your `nginx` configuration:

```
rewrite "^/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}(/.*)$" $1 permanent;
```

It is possible to place it inside a `location` block, but as that location block would need to use a regular expression too, it would probably save processing if this rewrite is left naked in the server context, that is placed somewhere near the top of your `server` block.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.